# Different API & SegmentInfos constants after upgrade Lucene from 3.6 to 4.1

Tags: java, lucene

I'm in the middle of upgrading the Lucene engine for indexing my content from version 3.6 to 4.1. I've noticed that some parties of API has been widely changed.

Especially when it comes to statics constants from SegmentInfos class...

My old code uses following pieces of code for detecting corrupted indexes. If any, then removes Lucene binary files:

```
for (String name : fileNames) {
    if (name != null && name.startsWith("segments_")) {
        IndexInput input = dir.openInput(name);
        int format = input.readInt();
        input.close();
        if (format != SegmentInfos.FORMAT_DIAGNOSTICS) {
            LOG.info(String.format("File %s is corrupted and it will be deleted", name));
            dir.deleteFile(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly static constant SegmentInfos.FORMAT_DIAGNOSTICS in 4.1 version of Lucene is gone and I have not clue how to now recognize whether some index is corrupted or not...

Comment: Why were you doing that manually? There is the checkindex tool for that. Or at least you can have a look at its code which should do similar things.

Comment: Indeed there is a checkindex tool which I wasn't aware. I will have a look on it, and it is probably what I need... thanks.

Comment: nice to hear, I added my comment as a new answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed quite some non backward compatible changes in Lucene 4. That's the main reason why the major version has changed.

But looking at what you are doing manually, I would suggest you to have a look at the [check index tool](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html). It allows you to check the health of your index and optionally drop broken segments. If you can't use the tool itself you can at least have a look at its code and see how you can integrate it in your application.